# amazon webservices ec2 micro pricing for processor and memory usage

Tags: amazon-ec2

If I have AmazonWS EC2 micro instance, should I pay for memory/processor usage as well?

I mean there are the prices: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Micro instance then cost: $0.020 per Hour = 14.4 $ for month. This is, if this instance is just launched. But will I pay additional fee if let's say processor&memory is loaded for 100% all that time?

This not clear still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

1 Linux micro server with 100% utilization for a month = $14.64

Comment: and what about EBS storage that attached to the instance, should I pay for this?

Comment: ahh, I found:
EBS: $0.10 per GB-month of provisioned storage ;  
I/O: $0.10 per 1 million I/O requests